Cqlsh No module named 'six.moves'
I have already installed "six" 1.7.2 in python 2.7.18 with pip, but i receive an error message anyway.
seva@seva-HLYL-WXX9:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.18

seva@seva-HLYL-WXX9:~$ pip install six==1.7.2
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Requirement already satisfied: six==1.7.2 in ./.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.7.2)

seva@seva-HLYL-WXX9:~$ cqlsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 130, in <module>
    from six.moves import configparser, input
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'

seva@seva-HLYL-WXX9:~$ pip show six
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Name: six
Version: 1.7.2
Summary: Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
Home-page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/
Author: Benjamin Peterson
Author-email: benjamin@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /home/seva/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: thrift

Answer
If you want to use python2.7, open cqlsh.py with nano:
sudo nano /usr/bin/cqlsh.py

And change python3 on python2.7.

type cqlsh ? head -1 /usr/bin/cqlsh ? head -1 /usr/bin/cqlsh.py ?

@phd head -1 /usr/bin/cqlsh returns #!/bin/sh and head -1 /usr/bin/cqlsh.py returns #!/usr/bin/python3. It means that cqlsh supports only python3, rigth? I dont know python :(

I don't know about "only python3" but this particular installation uses python3 so your pip show six is irrelevant as it runs under a different Python (2.7); Python packages are not global, every major Python version on a system has its own sets of packages. You need to restart your investigation. Please [edit] and add the text output from /usr/bin/python3 -m pip show six
